# Unable to identify value of EditText variable (appcompat error) and convert edit text successfully

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I am currently trying to figure out how I can see the value of an edit text variable. In my code I am trying to take a user entered number and apply mathematics to it to produce a tip calculator. Only issue is, if the user has not entered any values for the Edit Text variable to initialize to, the value of the Edit Text variable is not null or even an empty string but an absurdly long line of code listed here:
**android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{1b372dd VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07009b app:id/userInput}**

That is the value of the Edit Text variable called userInputAmount that was initialized with the method findViewById with the parameters (R.id.userInput)

**However the error occurs** when I try to bind the value of that Edit Text variable **userInputAmount** to a double value **userAmount** by using the Double.parseDouble method with the parameters (userInputAmount.getText().toString())

The reason why I need to actually identify the value of the EditText is so that I can make a logic gate that bypasses the double conversion so it wont crash my app.

What I would like to do is this

```
if(editTextVariable != null && editTextVariable != "")

//Do the double conversion

else

//set the double variable equal to 0 so it wont crash the app.
```

TLDR: I need to figure out the value of the Edit Text in order to create a logic gate to bypass conversion if the value is **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{1b372dd VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07009b app:id/userInput}**  I would also prefer not to initialize the edit text variable to that if the value is that. I was thinking maybe check the value of the xml reference (userInput) with an if statement before initializing but I'm unaware of how to do so.

The error occurs with this statement

```
userAmount = Double.parseDouble(userInputAmount.getText().toString());
```

Below is the code and xml

```
package com.example.frankbuddy.advancedtipcalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.graphics.Color;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SeekBar tipSeekBar;
int seekBarValue;

//For custom tip percentage ($%)
TextView tipDisplay;

//For applied custom percentage to user input (#.#$)
TextView tipAmountDisplay;

//For 15% tip
TextView defTipAmount;

//For Default 15% tip total amount
TextView defTotalAmount;

//For Custom % tip total amount
TextView mainTotalAmount;

//For user input amount
EditText userInputAmount;


double userAmount;

double defaultTip;

double defaultTotal;

double userTotalTip;

double userCustomTotal;

private final int ORANGE = 0xFFFF3300;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initialize custom percentage display amount
    tipDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipDisplayPercentage);
    //Intialize user input amount edit text
    userInputAmount =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    //Initialize tip amount display
    tipAmountDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tipDisplayAmount);
    //Initialize default tip amount
    defTipAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.defaultTipAmount);
    //Initialize default total amount
    defTotalAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.defaultTotalAmount);
    //Initialize custom total amount
    mainTotalAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customTotalAmount);

    userTotalTip = 0.0;

    userCustomTotal = 0.0;

    defaultTotal = 0;

    defaultTip = 0;

    userAmount = 0;





    //Seek Bar initialize
    tipSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    tipSeekBar.setMax(100);
    tipSeekBar.setProgress(15);

    //Display initial custom tip amount (Default 15%)
    tipDisplay.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    tipDisplay.setText(tipSeekBar.getProgress() + "%");


    //Seek bar listener
    tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        //initialize progress value (To be used for display and math)
        int progressChangedValue = 0;


        //Realtime listener for updates
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            //Set progress changed value
            progressChangedValue = progress ;

            //Update custom display percentage amount
            tipDisplay.setText(progressChangedValue + "%");


            if(progressChangedValue <= 20)
            {
                tipDisplay.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if(progressChangedValue >= 21 && progressChangedValue <= 29)
            {
                tipDisplay.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            //Display warning if progress value meets or exceeds 30%
            if(progressChangedValue >= 30)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Warning, Tip is now exceeding 30% and the value is now " + progressChangedValue + "%",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                tipDisplay.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }



            //Bind user input amount into a double variable to apply mathematics
            userAmount = Double.parseDouble(userInputAmount.getText().toString());

            //Do math for custom tip amount
            userTotalTip = userAmount * progressChangedValue *.01;
            tipAmountDisplay.setText(String.format("%.2f", userTotalTip));

            //Do math for custom total amount
            userCustomTotal = userTotalTip + userAmount;
            mainTotalAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f", userCustomTotal));


            //Do math for default tip amount
            defaultTip = userAmount * .15;
            defTipAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f", defaultTip));

            //Do math for default total amount
            defaultTotal = defaultTip + userAmount;
            defTotalAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f",defaultTotal ));

        }

        //Listener for first changes
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {

        }

        //Listener for when the user stops manipulating the bar
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {


        }

    });
}
```

And XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipDisplayAmount"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/defaultTipAmount"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipDisplayPercentage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Total"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Amount $"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/userInput"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Custom %"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userInput"
    android:layout_width="207dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="0.00"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="209dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userInput" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="Tip"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="15%"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipDisplayPercentage"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/defaultTipAmount"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/defaultTotalAmount"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/defaultTipAmount"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customTotalAmount"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/defaultTotalAmount"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipDisplayAmount"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is speculation, but it looks like when `getText()` returns null, Java calls `toString()` on the EditText itself. What you're seeing is the String representation of the EditText instance (it's AppCompat because you're using an AppCompatActivity).

Instead of using

```
userAmount = Double.parseDouble(userInputAmount.getText().toString());
```

You should be checking the null/empty state:

```
Editable text = userInputAmount.getText();
if (text == null || text.toString.length < 1) userAmount = 0; //or whatever you want as the default value
else userAmount = Double.parseDouble(text.toString());
```